# Django storing entry to database that is shouldn't

Tags: python, django

If I have the following model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    Fname = models.CharField(max_length = 20, blank = False)
    Lname = models.CharField(max_length = 20, blank = False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 254, unique = True, db_index = True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

And in the shell I try:

```
user = User()
user.save()
```

Shouldn't store user to the database, but it does. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the value of `email` in the stored row?

Comment: Why shouldn't it? What makes you think that?

Comment: since blank = False, I thought that if the constraint is violated it would not store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As per documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save), `save()` doesn't perform any validation on you model. If you want validation, you have to run it manually.